# Android - touch tolerance best practice

Tags: android, android-gesture

I can detect touch for my tiles and it works well from programmer's point of view. But I would love to increase an usability as well. See screenshot:

The idea is simple - if user touches some tile an action is performed. The problem is when user touches point close to two tiles. Currently I just do simple maths and select one. But this is not ergonomic. User might wanted to touch the second tile but his touch was not precise enough.

[image]

I am looking for best practice for such situation. `onTouchEvent` returns a single event so I cannot guess the touch direction. I lean to build some tolerance (e.g. 5 dp) and ignore such ambiguous events. Is there a better practice? And how big the tolerance area shall be?

Comment: see `MotionEvent#getSize`

Comment: I read javadoc already but I have no idea how to use this attribute for my case. Could you elaborate how it can give me information whether user wanted to press left or right tile?

Comment: the size is how "fat" your fingers are, unfortunately your fingers are not perfect round, so it cannot be a radius, you need some heuristics to use it